# using sum,count on the same column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table where i have actions and messages as columns i want to count of particular actions on particular datetime i was able to sum on every action but not count on particular action.

```
SELECT DATE(datetime),carpark_name,
Sum(CASE action when '2' then 1 else 0 end) as AcceptedIMG,
Sum(CASE action when '3' then 1 else 0 end) as RejectedIMG, 
Sum(CASE action when '4' then 1 else 0 end) as ChangeIMG,  
sum(CASE action when '23' then 1 else 0 end) as AcceptedViolation,
sum(CASE action when '24' then 1 else 0 end) as RejectedViolation,
sum(CASE action when '25' then 1 else 0 end) as SkippedViolation,
FROM customer_1.audit_trail inner join customer_1.carparks on
customer_1.audit_trail.location_id =  customer_1.carparks.id
 where DATE(datetime)> '2013-12-01'and DATE(datetime)< '2013-12-03'  and location_id = '146'
```

But this is what I need adding it  count(AcceptedIMG, RejectedIMG,ChangeIMG,) or (count(action(2,3,4) as review. I am not able to do this.

Comment: That SUM is doing the COUNT. You need to GROUP BY DATE(datetime),carpark_name to get your results correctly.

Comment: I mean to add these actions of(2,3,4) as review.(eg.like action(2+3+4 =XX) as review

Comment: Not understanding what you are trying to do. Could you add the expected output and more detail of what you are looking for?

Comment: i need sum of action (2,3,4) as review and sum(23,24,25) as contravention. LIKE ............................................ ..................datetime   carpark, accepted , rej,change, review  .................2013-12-03  ebbwale    5         4    3        12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the SUM of action 2,3 and 4, as column REVIEW and 23,24,25 as CONTRAVENTIO you could do:

```
SELECT DATE(datetime),
       carpark_name,
       Sum(CASE action when '2' then 1 else 0 end) as AcceptedIMG,
       Sum(CASE action when '3' then 1 else 0 end) as RejectedIMG, 
       Sum(CASE action when '4' then 1 else 0 end) as ChangeIMG,  
       SUM(CASE WHEN action IN ('2','3','4') then 1 else 0 end) as REVIEW
       sum(CASE action when '23' then 1 else 0 end) as AcceptedViolation,
       sum(CASE action when '24' then 1 else 0 end) as RejectedViolation,
       sum(CASE action when '25' then 1 else 0 end) as SkippedViolation,
       SUM(CASE WHEN action IN ('23','24','25') then 1 else 0 end) as CONTRAVENTION
FROM customer_1.audit_trail 
INNER join customer_1.carparks 
   ON customer_1.audit_trail.location_id =  customer_1.carparks.id
WHERE DATE(datetime) > '2013-12-01'
  AND DATE(datetime) < '2013-12-03'  
  AND location_id = '146'
GROUP BY DATE(datetime),carpark_name
```

I just added the two columns to your query. If you don't need the individual ones, you can remove them.